# Can't build android app with API 22

Tags: android, api, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is my gradle.build file:
https://paste.fedoraproject.org/366276/09908146/

But when I tried to sync gradle or build apk. I have this errors:

```
C:\Users\alex\AndroidStudioProjects\Pieceofcake\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml

Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Error:(24) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

And no, I don't want use 23 API. Never. Because google changed permission structure, and I don't want write workarounds for 6+. How to fix it with 22 API?

Answer (score 0):

I think if build tool 22.0.0 and 21.0.0 is not preexist in your build tool folder then you need to download it and paste in sdk build tool folder. then you can access this library features if you don't want to use v-23.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are using:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```

This library has a dependency with

```
  <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
  <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
  <version>23.2.1</version>
```

You can check [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.facebook.android%7Cfacebook-android-sdk%7C4.11.0%7Caar).

It causes the issue because using support v23, **you have to compile** with API 23.
Use:

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
```

> And no, I don't want use 23 API. Never. Because google changed permission structure, and I don't want write workarounds for 6+. How to fix it with 22 API?

**It is wrong.** It doesn't depend by api used to compile but by the `targetSdkVersion`.

Check the [doc](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html):

> - if the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.
> - If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, and it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running. The user can grant or deny each permission, and the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user denies a permission request.

Hovewer it is very important to note that:

> Note: Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), **users can revoke permissions from any app at any time, even if the app targets a lower API level**. You should test your app to verify that it behaves properly when it's missing a needed permission, regardless of what API level your app targets.